# question mark operator (?) before variables - what do they do in rust?

Tags: rust

I'm improving my rusty skills lately and saw (in some Copilot suggestions) the question mark operator used as a prefix of variables:

```rust
debug!(?raw); // raw is of type String

// Also

match self.subnet_tx.send((raw, addr)) {
    Ok(_size) =>  continue,
    Err(err: SendError<(String, SocketAddr)>) => {
        error!(cause = ?err, "error sending to channel");
        continue;
    }
};
```

Obviously I googled it and read about the ? operator - yet, I could not find any useful information about that.

The closest piece of information I did find was related to the `?Sized` trait.

Can anyone explain what is it used for? Should it be used? In which cases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no "question mark before variables" in rust. However it can be used as a token in *macros* and seeing that your code uses it only in macros I believe that is the case here. If you would provide where `debug` and `error` macro come from it could be confirmed.

EDIT. Those macros are from [tracing](https://crates.io/crates/tracing) crate. As the [documentation](https://docs.rs/tracing/0.1.37/tracing/index.html#using-the-macros) says:

> The ? sigil is shorthand that specifies a field should be recorded using its fmt::Debug implementation

So this is not some general convention, but rather some specific syntax that designers of tracing crate chose.

Comment: thanks, I'm seeing this in Copilot suggestion, I assume the macros are from the "tracing" crate. actually removing the question mark from the err triggers a compiler error saying `the trait bound ......: Value` is not satisfied.....

Comment: I also looked into macros, in the rust book did not found nothing. So I thought its maybe some convention or something

Comment: I feel so dumb, did not cross my mind that its a macro only thing and that its a specific crate implementation. Thank you for your help